# Proving hypothetical sylloligism (p implies q, q implies r, therefore p implies r) with boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to prove the hypothetical sylloligism using boolean algebra.  We already have a solution using propositional logic, which relies on proof by contradiction. [$(p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies r) \implies (p \implies r)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758111/p-implies-q-wedge-q-implies-r-implies-p-implies-r)

Can this be shown simply by simplifying a boolean algebra equation?

$$ (p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies r) = (p \implies r) $$
can represented in boolean algebra as
$$(\overline{p}+q)(\overline{q}+r)=\overline{p} + r$$

Doing math unto it, I get:

$$
\overline{p}\overline{q} + \overline{p}r + q\overline{q} + qr = \overline{p}+r \\
\overline{p}\overline{q} + \overline{p}r + qr = \overline{p}+r \\
$$

From here, I'm not seeing where to proceed.  Is $\overline{p}(\overline{q} + r)$ more useful than, say, $r(\overline{p} + q)$?  Am I incorrect in equating $(p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies r) = (p \implies r)$?  The related link uses implication, and I'm not sure I understand why.

Any advice on what's next?

A few notes: This sounds like a homework question, but it's not.  We're unconstrained in how we solve it (provided it's solved using boolean algebra, the whole point of this endeavor).  Also, I can show the equivalence using truth tables and karnaugh maps if I so chose, but I'm looking for the methodology, not the answer.

Comment: But how you changed $(p \implies q)∧(q \implies r) \implies (p \implies r)$ into $(p \implies q)∧(q \implies r) = (p \implies r)$ ?

Comment: That's one of the points I'm unsure of.  Given $(p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies r)$ and trying to show that $p \implies r$ should I be equating them?  Or, should they be implied?  I'm trying to prove that the two forms are equal, or at least, that's how I'm rationalizing it to myself.

Comment: If (p⟹r), does  (p⟹q)∧(q⟹r) follow?  Well, suppose p=1, r=1, and q=0.  Then (p⟹r)=1, but [(p⟹q)∧(q⟹r)]=0.  So, (p⟹r) doesn't imply (p⟹q)∧(q⟹r).  Thus, you would do better to try and show that {[(p⟹q)∧(q⟹r)]⟹(p⟹r)}=1.

Comment: @Doug So, if I understand properly, by equating them, I was trying to prove $(p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies r) \iff (p \implies r)$?  I can understand why that didn't work.

Comment: @Phox Not quite.  By equating them, you ended up implying that [((p⟹q)∧(q⟹r))⟺(p⟹r)], which is false.

Comment: I see.  I wonder, then, if this question should be closed, since the central premise was off.  At this point, it degenerates to just a mathematical error.

Comment: @Phox - the error you made is the following: "equatin" both memebers, you assumed that $(p \implies q)∧(q \implies r) \equiv (p \implies r)$ is a *tautology*, and it is **not**, while $(p \implies q)∧(q \implies r) \implies (p \implies r)$ **is** taut.

Comment: The "general rule" in order to exploit the "isomorphism" between propositional logic and boolean algebra is : replace complement by negation ($\lnot$), product by conjunction ($\land$) and sum by disjunction ($\lor$) hand you will have that a formula $\mathcal F$ is a *tautology* iff its "boolean transform" $\mathcal F^*$ satisfy the equation $\mathcal F^*=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hypothetical syllogism is a theorem, then:

$$(p\overline{q})+(q\overline{r}) + \overline{p} + r = 1.$$

Here is one way of demonstrating that:

$$\overline{(p\overline{q})+(q\overline{r}) + \overline{p} + r} = 0.$$

$$(\overline{p} + q)(\overline{q} + r) p \overline{r} = 0.$$

$$p (\overline{p} + q)\overline{r}(\overline{q} + r) = 0.$$

$$(p\overline{p} + pq)(\overline{r}\overline{q} + \overline{r}r) = 0.$$

$$(0 + pq)(\overline{r}\overline{q} + 0) = 0.$$

$$(pq)(\overline{r}\overline{q}) = 0.$$

$$(p\overline{r})(q\overline{q}) = 0.$$

$$(p\overline{r})(0) = 0.$$

$$0 = 0.$$

I didn't read the comments, so I suspect you already got a satisfactory answer, but if not, this might be of some help. If some step is wrong or unclear, leave a comment and we'll find the appropriate rule of boolean algebra that justifies it.

---

Since you explicitly asked for a direct proof and I am stuck at an airport, I'll add the following:

$$(p\overline{q})+(q\overline{r}) + \overline{p} + r = 1.$$

$$(~(p\overline{q})+ \overline{p}~) + (~(q\overline{r}) + r~) = 1.$$

$$(~\overline{q} + \overline{p}~) + (~q + r~) = 1.$$

$$(~\overline{q} + q~) + (~\overline{p} + r~) = 1.$$

$$(1) + (~\overline{p} + r~) = 1.$$

$$1 + \dots = 1.$$

Comment: Oh my... Take heart, Phox. Boolean algebra is about the worst way to do proofs like this. If you haven't already, you will probably learn much easier ways very soon. (See truth tables, natural deduction.)

Comment: Not so frightening.  I was working in Boolean algebra because, as an electrical engineer, it's what I'm more familiar with.  It's definitely more elegant when expressed using logic, but I don't think I've developed enough intuition yet to be able to manipulate logic adeptly.

Answer (score 1):

Given boolean $p,q,r$, you want to prove $( p \Rightarrow q ) \wedge ( q \Rightarrow r ) \Rightarrow ( p \Rightarrow r )$. Since $( x \Rightarrow y ) \equiv ( \neg x \vee y )$ for any boolean $x,y$, what we want to prove is equivalent to $((p'+q)(q'+r))'+(p'+r) = 1$. This can be checked simply by expanding everything and collecting terms:

$((p'+q)(q'+r))'+(p'+r) = (p'+q)'+(q'+r)'+(p'+r) = pq'+qr'+(p'+r)$

$ = (pq'+p')+(qr'+r) = (q'+p')+(q+r) = (q'+q)+p'+r = 1+p'+r = 1$

Note that in the 4th equality I used the following identity:

$x+x'y = xy+xy'+x'y = (xy+xy')+(xy+x'y) = x(y+y') + (x+x')y$

$ = x+y$ for any boolean $x,y$

In general it will always be possible to prove any tautology in propositional logic using boolean algebra, by expanding everything as in the first line of the solution I gave above and then further dividing each term into the smallest possible pieces given the variables involved. For example $r = pqr+pq'r+p'qr+p'q'r$. After that it is straightforward to check whether all pieces are covered. However this may result in an exponential number of pieces and can often be avoided by a little more clever manipulation as in the second line of the solution. But I'm not sure if there are cases that require an exponentially sized proof...